# SQL Server 2012: correct trigger does not fire after insert

Tags: sql-server-2012, triggers

I have 2 triggers for 2 tables. Both create numbers, one creates an `articlenumber`, the other an `ordernumber`.

Articlenumber:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_CreateArtikelnummer] 
ON [dbo].[tblArtikel] 
AFTER INSERT
AS
    IF ((SELECT TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL()) < 2)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @ArtikelID INT;
        DECLARE @LfID INT;  --supplierID
        DECLARE @ProdID INT

        --  ---Wein, Traubensaft, Sekt
        SET @ArtikelID = (SELECT
                              CASE WHEN Artikelart = 'Wein' THEN 1 
                                   WHEN Artikelart = 'Traubensaft' THEN 2 
                                   WHEN Artikelart = 'Sekt' THEN 3 
                              END AS ArtikelID 
                          FROM inserted)

        SET @LfID = (SELECT Lfid FROM inserted)
        SET @ProdID = (SELECT ProdID FROM inserted)

        SET @Prodid = (SELECT COUNT(ProdID) 
                       FROM [dbo].[tblArtikel] 
                       WHERE Lfid = @LfID)  

        UPDATE dbo.tblArtikel 
        SET Artikelnummer = CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(NCHAR(1), @ArtikelID) +
                            CONVERT(NCHAR(3), FORMAT(@LfID, '000')) + CONVERT(NCHAR(4), FORMAT(@ProdID,'0000'))) 
        FROM inserted 
        INNER JOIN dbo.tblArtikel ON inserted.prodid = dbo.tblArtikel.prodid
```

This one fires IMMEDIATELY when inserting date in the table by hand (for test purpose) and displays the generated `articlenumber` instantely.

Ordernumber: should be build from the running number per year for each supplier, so 1703001 stands for year 2017, supplierID 03, ordernumber 001

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_CreateBestellnummer] 
ON [dbo].[tblOrders] 
AFTER INSERT
AS
IF ((SELECT TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL()) < 2)

BEGIN
    --set nocount on;

    declare @Jahr int
    declare @LfID int  --supplierID
    declare @OrderID int
    declare @Order int
    --declare @Bestelldatum date

    set @Jahr=(select right(year(getdate()),2))

    set @LfID=(SELECT Lfid from inserted)
    --SELECT @OrderID=INSERTED.OrderID from inserted

    set @Order=(SELECT count(OrderID) from [dbo].[tblOrders] where Lfid=@LfID and year(Bestelldatum)=Year(Getdate()))

    Update dbo.tblOrders set Bestellnummer=convert(int,convert(nchar(2),@Jahr)+convert(nchar(2),FORMAT(@LfID, '00'))+convert(nchar(3),format(@Order,'000'))) 
        from INSERTED inner join dbo.tblOrders on INSERTED.OrderID= dbo.tblOrders.OrderID
```

This one does NOT fire at once, when finishing inserting date into the table and does NOT display the generated ordernumber.

I get a red exclamation mark on the left side of the records saying something like "data are write protected. Execute query again".
When I click the execute button on the menue the the trigger fires and updates the correct ordernumber.

What can be the reason?
Thanks
Michael

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` statement that causes this trigger to fire inserts 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `set @LfID = (SELECT Lfid from inserted)` - it's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: Thanks Marc, but I cannot confirm it or better say, I cannot understand it, because this when I insert one row by hand in the table there should be only one row in the INSERTED table. Otherwise I do not understand why the first trigger on tblArticle works properly. I you find an error I would appreciate if you could correct it, as I do not find a mistake. Michael